# Is it possible to identify the user whose credentials are used to call the Google Cloud API?

Tags: authentication, ssh, google-cloud-platform

**Question:**

Is there a Google Cloud API call I can use to identify the user whose credentials are being used to call the Google Cloud API?

**Details:**

My objective is to dynamically provision an SSH key to an EC2 Instance for one-time use, so I'm editing a Compute Instance's `ssh-key` metadata to include the public portion of the SSH key on the fly. GCloud requires that I include a username when specifying the SSH key, and I'd like to use the name of the user whose credentials are being used to add the SSH key via the Google Cloud API.

Looking at the [IAM API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/), and [Compute Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/), I don't see any API calls that I can make to identify the currently calling user. In AWS, I have https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html, which does exactly what I want.

Does Google Cloud's API support this feature? Or is there some other hack I could use?

**Update:** I discovered that in fact, I don't need this feature to accomplish my use case! The "username" GCP asks for is the Linux user I'll use to SSH into the Compute Instance, not the GCP user.

Comment: Is the user creating the GCE instance themselves via an API call to GCP or are you providing an interface that the user is calling and then your code creates the instance?

Comment: How are you gaining access to the credentials that the user is using?

Comment: In localdev, I'm using `gcloud`, which has somehow configured my environment. In my CI system, I'm writing a JSON Web Token to a file on the file system and setting an env var, `GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY, to point to the location of that JSON Web Token. I'm building a testing framework, so the user makes use of functions I've defined to run tests, and those functions call the GCP API.

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but since you have the JWT you have the credentials and the identity for the API. How are you identifying the users that call your code? Another item, when you create a GCE instance, the SSH login name will be determined by the credentials that is calling the create instance API.  You could use any SSH key pair that you want, give the user the private key and username then put the public key in metadata. This username is what you use with the public key in the metadata.

Comment: Note: I am not actually sure but I don't think the username at the end of the public key actually matters when you are using GCE metadata to create an instance.

Comment: My challenge was that the code (https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest) could be called by either my local env, or a CI env, or something else. Depends on how library users use it. Users are responsible for auth'ing themselves directly to GCP. Got the SSH working and you're correct that the username at the end doesn't matter. But the username at the very beginning is the SSH login name that's used, independently of the GCP user updating the metadata.

Comment: I am not sure how you are implementing this. If the user is authenticating with GCP, then you don't have access to who they are. Ignoring that, if you look at the HTTP headers for an API request, you will see a header `Authorization: Bearer token`. The `token` is a Json Web Token (JWT). If you decode this, you will see the email account associated with the API request. GCP has an endpoint that you can call to decode a Authorization Token. I will have to find that endpoint document. Let me know if you need it.

Comment: Here are two document that might help you. "Access User Data with Secure Tokens". https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/securetoken . "Token Service REST API Reference", which is similar to AWS STS https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/reference/securetoken/rest/v1/token

Comment: Here is that token endpoint document that I mentioned: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/auth/application-default/print-access-token

Comment: Ah, https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/securetoken seems to have what I'm looking for!

Comment: Can you please summarize your solution in a new answer so others will easily find it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's tokeninfo end point to return information about the current authenticated user. An example in Python is shown below. The "id tokens" that Google users are actually JWTs, which are base64-encoded JSON payloads, separated by ".". You can also parse those directly to get the identity, without needing a remote call. For more information, see [Google's tokeninfo documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint).

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests
credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())
print('project id:', project_id)
print('id token:', credentials.id_token)
response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=' + credentials.id_token)
print('tokeninfo:')
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

bash version of it, requires `gcloud`, `curl` and `awk`

```
#!/bin/sh

PROJECT=$(gcloud config list project --format text | awk '{print $2}')
echo
echo "project id: $PROJECT"
echo

TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-identity-token)
echo "token: $TOKEN"
echo

echo "tokeninfo: "
curl -s https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=$TOKEN
```